# Vue.js slots error _vm.Edit is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm still learning Vue and I am using a component vue-tables-2. I'm trying to use slots but it keeps returning below error

> _vm.Edit is not a function

My **table.vue** component

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory">
    <v-client-table :data="inventory" :columns="columns"
      :options="options" name="inventoryAssets">
        <a slot="Edit" slot-scope="props" class="fa fa-edit" :href="Edit(props.row.id)">Edit</a>
    </v-client-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import inventoryTable from '@/components/inventoryTable';
import Edit from '@/components/Edit';


export default {
  components: {
    Edit
  },

  data() {
    return {
      columns: [],
      inventory: [],
      errors: [],
      Edit: Edit
    };
  },

  created() {
     this.getInventory();
  },

  methods: {
    getInventory: function( inventory ) {
      axios.get( 'http://localhost:3000/assets' )
        .then( ( response ) => {
          for ( let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++ ) {
            this.inventory = response.data;
            this.columns = Object.keys( response.data[i] );
          }
        }).catch( ( e ) => {
          this.errors.push( e );
        });
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

My **Edit.vue** component

```
<template>
  <a class="fa fa-edit" :href="Edit(data.id)">Edit</a>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    'data',
    'index'
  ]
};
</script>
```

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Hi, what is `Edit` in the `:href` in the table component and in the edit component? Is it declared in the components' methods?

Comment: No sorry it's a component that I have defined in the data method.  I've updated original post to show Table scripting